# How to connect to gitlab from the terminal?

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

I usually access to a repo in gitlab from the browser. I am having some problems doing that today, so I have been instructed to "connect to the repo from a terminal".

How can I do that?

I mean, I just want to check that I can access the repo from a machine.
I know that I can clone a repo from the terminal, but that is not what I want to do. I don't need to clone the whole repo to a machine. I just want to see if I can access (or connect) the repo from the machine

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```bash
git  ls-remote -h <repo url/remote path>
```

e.g. `git  ls-remote -h git@github.com:repo/origin.git`

If you do not have the access you will see error:

> ERROR: Repository not found.
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Otherwise, it will show refs to the branches.

Comment: `-h` can list a *lot*. I use `HEAD` to check for basic connectivity, `git ls-remote $path_or_url HEAD`